# How to fetch data using function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this function in functions.php and I want to fetch data using this function

```
function getQuestionByNumber($number){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE id = '$number'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row;
    }
```

What I am trying to do is using this function I want to fetch question from question table on the test page
Heres my test page code:

```
<?php
    include('includes/conn.php');
    include('includes/functions.php');

    $number = $_GET['num'];
    $ques = getQuestionByNumber($number);
?>

<textarea readonly><?php echo $ques['question']; ?></textarea>
```

But it is giving error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineExam\testingques.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineExam\testingques.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineExam\testingques.php on line 10

Can someone please help me I am a beginner and just started building applications

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you, I will update my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try do something like

```
function getQuestionByNumber($db, $number)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!